# How many solutions to $|x_1| + x_2 + x_3 = 16$?

Tags: combinatorics

I want to know how many solutions there are to the equation $|x_1| + x_2 + x_3 = 16$
with $x_1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $x_2,x_3$ in $\mathbb{N}$.

My two attempts to solve this question were:

1. solve this question with normal combinatorial ways using ${n+ k - 1 \choose n}$ and since $x_1$ can be both negative and positive I'll count this twice, in this attempt i assume that the solution $x_1 = -1 , x_2 = 10, x_3 = 5$, is different then , $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 10, x_3 = 5$.
2. other way of thinking was to split this to two cases:
   a. $x_1$ is a natural number
   b. $x_1$ is a negative number
   however I couldn't think of a good way doing this counting without counting lots of solutions several times

Comment: I am not sure what the problem asks for, by N do you mean the positive integers? Then the combinatorial way needs to be modified. Also, the doubling idea is not quite right, the cases $x_1=0$ don't get doubled.

Comment: yes N stands for the positive integers including 0.and Z stands for all integers including the negative ones

Comment: Then double like you wanted to do, and then adjust. Doubling also doubles the cases where $x_1=0$, so subtract the number of solutions of shape $(0,x_2,x_3)$, which is obviously $17$ but can also be computed by formula.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment, it looks as if you want $x_2$ and $x_3$ to be *non-negative* integers, while $x_1$ is an integer.

There are $\binom{18}{16}$ solutions of $y+x_2+x_3=16$ in non-negative integers. Any solution  where $y\ne 0$ produces a  solution of $|x_1|+x_2+x_3=16$ by taking $x_1=-y$.  But a solution with $y=0$ does not produce anything new. So $2\binom{18}{2}$ double-counts the solutions of $|x_1|+x_2+x_3=16$ with $x_1=0$. Adjust by subtracting the number of such solutions, which is $\binom{17}{16}$, or more simply $17$.

Thus the total number of solutions of our original problem is $\binom{18}{16}-\binom{17}{16}$.